# Egoroff's Theorem implies positive measure on the sequence of measurable sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am struggling to understand Halmos "Measure Theory" 21.2 where he says

If *E* is a measurable set of positive finite measure and if {f<sub>n</sub>} is a sequence of a.e. finite valued measurable functions which is fundamental a.e., then there exists a positive finite constant c and a measurable subset of *F* of *E* of positive measure such that, for every n=1,2, ... and for every x in F, | f<sub>n</sub> (x)| ≤ c

Halmos says that the proof of the above assertion uses Egoroff's theorem but I don't know how.

My attempt to prove this is the following:

First, let us remove all x from *E* where f<sub>n</sub>(x) is not fundamental. Thus I assume that E contains only the set of points where f<sub>n</sub>(x) is fundamental.

Let F<sub>n</sub>=$\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}${$x:| f_k (x)| ≤ n$}

Then $E\subset \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n$

Since $E \cap \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n$ approaches $E$,

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}m(E \cap \cup_{n=1}^{N} F_n )=m(E)>0$$

Thus there exist $N$ such that
$$m(E \cap \cup_{n=1}^{N} F_n)>0$$

$E \cap \cup_{n=1}^{N} F_n$ is such a set *F* and $c=N$.

Is this proof correct?
The above proof doesn't seem to require the measure of *E* to be finite. I'm not sure where we can use Egoroff's theorem.

Comment: What is a fundamental sequence? Halmos does not use this terminology. My copy of the book does not numbering like Theorem 21.2

Comment: Hi! It's not theorem 21.2. It's (2) at the end of chapter 21 with smaller text (page 90). The sequence $f_n$ of real valued function is fundamental a.e. if there exit a set $E_o$ and ε>0, then an integer $n_o$ can be found with the property that $|f_n (x) - f_m (x)| <ε$, whenever n≥$n_o$,m≥$n_o$.

Comment: You are using the term fundamental for Cauchy.

Comment: It's similar to Cauchy if the sequences are real, Here, the sequence is functions rather than numbers and Halmos defines the sequence of function that satisfies above relation as fundamental a.e.